# SQL Substring replacing for update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need your help real quick.... I use SQL 2008 R2

I have this column that has this kind of data

```
1_kka
2_bge
3_kil
```

the column should have only the number which is

```
1
2
3
```

So how should i replace it by using replace and substring?

Thank you!!

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2012 R2... it's either 2008R2 or 2012? :)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can do this remarkably easily by just adding 0 tot he string:

```
select col + 0
from t
```

The `+ 0` treats the string as an integer, and it automatically converts any numbers at the beginning of the string into a number.

In other databases, something like this will work:

```
select cast(left(col, 1) as int)
from t
```

Assuming that the initial number has exactly one digit (as in the examples in your question).

Comment: Sorry I use SQL 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server and if number is not limited to 1 digit you can use

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, CHARINDEX('_', column)-1)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

If multiple digits can appear before the underscore, you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(Fieldname,CHARINDEX('_',Fieldname)-1)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

This will update all values, in every row that contains your underscore.

```
Update TableName
Set FieldName = Substring(FieldName, 1, CharIndex('_', FieldName) - 1)
Where CharIndex('_', FieldName) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
update <TABLE> set COL = LEFT(COL,CHARINDEX('_', COL)-1)
```